# Reference for non-parallel harmonic $k$-forms

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

I want to get some deep understanding on *closed* *orientable* Riemannian manifolds admitting $k$-forms ($k\geq 2$) $\omega$ that satisfices the following conditions:
$$\nabla \omega\neq 0,\quad \Delta\omega=0.$$
where $\Delta=(\delta +d)^2$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator (Hodge Laplacian). What other useful properties can these forms have? Any reference would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are too many of these for them to have any particularly interesting structure.  For example, consider any metric $g$ on the $3$-torus $\mathbb{T}^3$.  By the Hodge theorem, the space of $g$-harmonic $2$-forms has dimension $3$.  However, if, say, all of them were $g$-parallel, then their duals would be a basis of $g$-parallel $1$-forms, which would imply that the metric $g$ is flat.  Thus, any non-flat metric $g$ on the $3$-torus will have a $g$-harmonic $2$-form that is not $g$-parallel.

In fact, as long as $H^2_{\mathrm{deRham}}(M^3,\mathbb{R})\not=0$, where $M$ is an orientable compact $3$-manifold, the generic metric $g$ on $M$ will have a $g$-harmonic $2$-form that is not $g$-parallel, since having a nonzero $g$-parallel $2$-form would force $g$ to be locally a product metric, and the generic metric is not locally a product.

Unfortunately, I think that there not much 'deep' to say about such $2$-forms in general.

Comment: Thanks professor. Do you know that these non-parallel forms are invariant under metric deformation? i.e. for a deformation of $g$ like $h$, $\nabla_h \omega\neq 0$ and $\Delta_h\omega=0$? (something like [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/75038/90655))

Comment: @C.F.G:  There's no reason to believe that a form of positive degree that is harmonic for one metric would be harmonic for a different metric.  If $\omega$ is closed (which doesn't depend on the metric), you are asking whether  $\mathrm{d}(\ast_h\omega) = 0$ for a metric $h$, which is a non-trivial first-order system of pde for $h$ as long as $\omega$ is nonzero, and it is generally weaker than the equation $\nabla_h\omega = 0$ (which is also a first order equation for $h$).

Comment: That's seems reasonable but I compare it with homotopy(homology) groups like loops homotopy class that are invariant under homeo.  but why these are not invariant under homeo intuitively?

Comment: @C.F.G:  I'm not sure what you mean.  The deRham cohomology group is a topological invariant, but the choice of a form representing a given cohomology class is not a topological invariant, there is not even a choice of a form that is a diffeomorphism invariant, since the diffeomorphisms homotopic to the identity don't fix any form of positive degree other than the form that vanishes identically.

Comment: Dear prof. Bryant, Your argument mainly based on that the dimension of $M$ is odd, Do you think that one can construct an example in even dimensions?

Comment: @C.F.G: Well, I chose 3 dimensions just because it was easier, but there are certainly examples in dimension 4 as well.  Let $M^4$ be a compact orientable 4-manifold that is simply-connected, not a product, does not support a Kähler metric, and yet does have non-trivial Betti number $b_2$.  (It's easy to construct such examples, for example, the oriented connected sum of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ with itself.)  Then every metric $g$ on it will have non-zero harmonic $2$-forms (by deRham's Theorem), but none of them can be $g$-paralell.